# Why does the PATCH of the HTTP method run the model save() method?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, patch

I use `serializers.ModelSerializer` and `viewsets.ModelViewSet` of Django REST Framework in my REST API.

While I was testing, I found out that the `PATCH` of `HTTP method` was running model `save()`.

I know `PATCH` is for updating data, Why DRF use `save()` instead of `update()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because update applies on a queryset and not a single instance and the update may alter more fields that provided by the clients which makes things hard to predict.

Answer (score 1):

Basically its happening [here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L80), inside `UpdateModelMixin`. The code is:

```
class UpdateModelMixin(object):
    ...
    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=partial)  # <-- Partial Update
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_update(serializer)

        if getattr(instance, '_prefetched_objects_cache', None):
            # If 'prefetch_related' has been applied to a queryset, we need to
            # forcibly invalidate the prefetch cache on the instance.
            instance._prefetched_objects_cache = {}

        return Response(serializer.data)

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
         serializer.save() # <-- here
```

And `UpdateModelMixin` is later subclassed by `ModelViewSet`.

Basically its using Serializer's [Partial](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#partial-updates) update feature.